# Как правильно составить LINQ запрос

Tags: c#, linq

Есть квадратный массив, например такой :

```
var arr = new [,] {{3, 3, 3, 2, 1 },
                   {2, 4, 3, 3, 3 },
                   {3, 3, 4, 3, 1 },
                   {2, 3, 5, 3, 1 }};
```

как составить запрос чтоб в ответе получить все индексы где лежит линия минимум из трех троек(и вертикальные , и горизонтальные).В этом примере в ответе должно быть 8 индексов.
Пример ответа:

```
List<Point> ordinates = new List<Point>
        {
           new Point( 0,1), new Point( 0,2),new Point( 0,3),
           new Point( 1,2), new Point( 1,3),new Point( 1,4),
           new Point( 2,3),
           new Point( 3,3)
        };
```

Comment: Linq не предназначен для работы с массивами размерности более чем 1. Написать, конечно, можно, но это будет не оч.

Comment: Ну и да, напишите какой на выходе должен быть результат и как он получается

Comment: На выходе хотелось бы получить список Point или кортежей с координатами. Координаты в ответе в этом примере 0,1 - 0,2 - 0,3 - 1,2 - 1,3 - 1,4 - 2,3 - 3,3

Comment: Получается уродство, поэтому я не хочу постить его ответом: https://ideone.com/UBr4nY Как по мне — такое лучше писать классическими циклами.

Comment: Страшновато , конечно, выглядит , но вам большое спасибо.